# Jquery class removed after link click, but second click is still recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little problem.  I'm trying to use Jquery `load()` function to load in stuff on a page using AJAX. After the content has been loaded, and the link gets tapped on a second time, I need to loaded content to slideup/hide;  And when the same link is clicked for the 3+ time, I need to just toggle the loaded content display, since it's already been loaded once.

My problem is that after clicking the link once, I remove the `loadable` class, but on the second click the same function executes as if the class were still there.  Here is my HTML:

```
<a title="Food" id="food" class="loadable" href="get-taste/food">Food</a>
<div class="food_load_space"></div>
```

The link triggers the load and the data loads into `.food_load_space`.  And here's my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.loadable').click(function(){ //executed upon link click 1;
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    linkid = $(this).attr('id');
    toload = url + ' #content-area';
    //now, remove loadable, add loaded and expanded
    $(this).removeClass('loadable');
    alert(toload);
    $('.' + linkid + '_load_space').load(toload);
    return false;
  }); //kill loadable
```

I'm also planning on adding an .expanded class and a `.loaded` class so that the script knows at which state the link is in.  But what happens is this function fires even if the `.loadable` class is gone.

Comment: please fix up the code section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event has already been bound to the element, you need to manually [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the event from the element(s) in question. This can be done by calling `$(this).unbind('click');`.

You may also wish to check if the element has the class in the event function.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried this, but after the unbind happens, the second call doesn't bind.  Gonna try to to check using a condition.

Comment: Ok this sucks.  For some reason, the second "click" doesn't bind.  So i'm just keeping it all in one function and just doing hasClass check.  THanks a lot for the idea!

Answer (score 3):

The handler is bound the the element, not the selector.

If you only want it to exist for one click, use the [`one()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to bind it.

```
$('a.loadable').one('click', function(){ 
    // and so on...
```

It will be automatically unbound after the first click.

Comment: Hi patrick, I tried this, but after the unbind happens, the second call doesn't bind.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The reason your second click is recognized is because jQuery has already binded an action to your element. You can't unbind the event just by removing the class. The class was only there to help you select that element (and style your element).

To remove the event binding, in your click function, you should do something like:

```
$('a.loadable').click(function() {
    ...your other code...
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

Comment: Hi Kchau, I tried this, but after the unbind happens, the second call doesn't bind.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!